# MinGWのg++にfilesystemヘッダが存在しない

Tags: c++, windows-10, gcc

windows10(32bit), gcc-6.3.0-1においてです。
MinGW Installerを用いてgccをインストールしましたが、`#include<filesystem>`や`#include<experimental/filesystem>`を含むcppファイルをコンパイルすると

```
hoge.c:3:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

のようにエラーが出てしまいます(experimental/filesystemのときも同様)。
コンパイルオプションには`-std=c++17`を付けています。また、調べたときに`-lstdc++fs`を付けるとよいという記事を見たので、試しましたが、変わりませんでした。

```
g++ -lstdc++fs
```

を実行すると

```
ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++fs
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

のようなエラーを吐くので、そもそもlibstdc++fs.aが存在しないのだと思い、MinGW/内をlibstdc++fsとfilesystemの二つで検索をかけたところ、どちらの名前のファイルも存在しませんでした。MinGWではfilesystemヘッダを利用する方法はないのでしょうか。

Comment: filesystem を有効にするためには、gcc をビルドする際に configure オプションで `--enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes` を指定する必要があります。ROCKTAKEY さんがお使いの MinGW gcc では指定されないでビルドされたのではないでしょうか。`gcc -v 2>&1 | grep filesystem` を実行して何も表示されなければ、ご自身で再ビルドするか、もしくはこのオプションが指定された状態でビルドされた gcc を入手してインストールする必要がありそうです。

Comment: <filesystem>への対応は、[GCC 8.xから](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017)ではないかと。[GCC 7.3.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HYvDLltmpKM9vi7A), [GCC 8.1.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vOhY0vlFyJmzdIjJ)

Comment: @alpha gcc 6.3.0 のソースコードには filesystem 関連のファイルがあって、libstdc++-v3/configure には `--enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts` フラグがありますので、ビルドはできそうです。ただ、6.3.0 では experimental なので最新版をインストールした方が良さそうですね。

Comment: @metropolis MinGW installerでのインストールであったため、自らビルドしていないのですが、MinGWはgccを--enable-libstdxx-filesystem-tsフラグを建てずにビルドしているということでしょうか。

Comment: @ROCKTAKEY [この issue](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/2292) を読むと、その様ですね。

Comment: ただ、[このコミット](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/commit/4b3a72eeb38484327a0bb3723f4974806b5e396f#diff-bab0b6146f93e7206c049f007d3e2249)で --enable-libstdxx-filesystem-ts を有効にしていますので、gcc 7.3.0 以降で導入した様です。ログを眺めると、その後 gcc 8.2.0 にアップデートする際にパッチを取り入れているので(2018/7/29)、やはり gcc の最新版をインストールした方が良いでしょうね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSYS2環境Mingw-w64 GCC 8.2.0で`<filesystem>`を利用できることを確認ました。GCCアップデート前の7系ではヘッダファイルがなくてエラーになった事から、@alphaさんのコメントの通りGCCでは8.xからの対応のようです。なお、リンク時に`-lstdc++fs`オプションは必須です。

MinGW GCCは現在メンテナンスされておらず、GCCも古いバージョンで止まっています。最新のC++規格を使いたい場合は、[Mingw-w64 GCC](http://mingw-w64.org/)を使用してください。Windowsでのビルド環境は[MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/)を用いるのが最も簡単でしょう。

Comment: 7系では‘<experimental/filesystem>‘に関してもヘッダファイルがなくてエラーになっていらっしゃいますか。

Comment: すみません、もうひとつ追加でお聞きしたいのですが、Mingw-w64 GCCのビルドは、32bit環境でも可能でしょうか。

Comment: `<experimental/filesystem>`を試す前に8系に上げてしまったので、7系でうまくいくかどうかはわかりません。

Comment: Mingw-w64 GCCは32bit版も用意されています。MSYS2も同様です。

Comment: なるほど、w64とついているのに32bitでも使用可能なのですね…ありがとうございました。